# Angular: Lib folder of module not included in node_modules folder

Tags: angular

I have an Angular module (Framework) which depends on another Angular module (pv-config).

The pv-config module is included as a git-submodule in the Framework module. When installing / building the following things happen:

Framework: `npm install`, which runs `"cd pv-config && npm install --no-save"`
Framework `npm run build`, which runs as a pre-build step: `"npm --prefix pv-config run build"`

When one then looks at the `framework/pv-config` folder, it will include the `lib` folder with the compiled files.

On Windows, the `framework/node_modules/pv-config` folder is a simlink to the `framework/pv-config` folder, and the framework can compile without any issue.

On Debian, the `framework/node_modules/pv-config` folder seems to be a partial copy of the `framework/pv-config` folder. It includes the `src` folder, but not the `lib` folder. This causes the compilation to fail, as the module `pv-config` cannot be found.

So my question is: how can I modify my package.json so that the `framework/pv-config/lib` folder will be included in the `framework/node_modules/pv-config` folder?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

May you need to create package on NPM to achieve it.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-and-publish-your-first-npm-package/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not looking to publish it on NPM. This module is for our internal use only. All I need is to make sure the lib folder is included in the node_modules folder on Debian, like it is on Windows.